# Starting from the point (1,1), in what direction does the function $φ = x^2 -y^2 +2xy$ decrease most rapidly?

Tags: calculus

Starting from the point (1,1), in what direction the function $φ = x^2 -y^2 +2xy$ decreases most rapidly?

The answer given is -***i*** found by calculating $-\frac{\Delta\phi}{||\Delta\phi ||}$ . In previous questions i have done, the direction of most rapid decrease has been found by $-\Delta\phi$ . Why is this different; is it because we are starting from point $(1,1)$ and not at point $(1,1)$ or is it because of a different reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the natural answer is $-\frac{\nabla\phi}{\|\nabla\phi\|}$, since we are after a *direction*, and it is natural that a direction is given by a unit vector. So, since, in this case, $\nabla\phi(1,1)=(4,0)$, the natural answer is $(-1,0)$. Of course, if someone say that the answer is $(-4,0)$, I can understand what is meant here. It just feels a little less natural. But ultimately it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Isn't $\nabla \varphi(1,1) = (2x+2y,-2y+2x)|_{(x,y) = (1,1)} = (4,0)$?

Comment: @psl2Z Yes. I had another function in my mind.